# Consecutive sentence citation in Chicago date-author style

Tags: citations, writing-style, citation-style

I am writing a paper in which I repeat a newspaper article citation.

"The New York Times article discusses the introduction of the AFB mainframe computer (Stevens, 1984). During an interview with a salesman, the AFB is called a "revolutionary tool" **(????)**."

Should I use the year, or the author's last name, or a different information, in the second, **bolded** citation?

I would like to avoid using "ibid."

Comment: Before I answer your question, can you please tell me if 
"The New York Times article discusses the introduction of the AFB mainframe computer (Stevens, 1984).'                                                                                                                       is your first citation

Comment: Hello, thank you - yes, it is the first time in the text this citation appears. There are others before it, but they refer to other sources.

Answer (score -1):

As the OP asks, they need a shortened version for all other citations. I don't know how your paper looks like, so this is the best response I can provide. Now, I don't wish to change your paper, but I would recommend for your first citation for that source is that you use one of the formats that have been listed in the second link.

Now to move on to your question. For all other citations from that source, I would recommend Author, Name of Newspaper. I would recommend the name of the newspaper because if you had any other sources made by the same author it would be easier to differentiate. And overall, I would still recommend that same format. I really hopes this helps. :)

https://library.menloschool.org/chicago/shortform

https://libguides.wvu.edu/c.php?g=418946&p=2855023

Comment: Whoever down voted me, I don't have a problem with that, I'm just wondering how I could fix my answers. Please reply, thank you.

Comment: I think your advice is not useful and also does not answer the question.